# How to correctly use :valid pseudoclass in mui components to change the border dynamically

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, pseudo-class

I'm trying to change the border color from Mui TextFields,, with createThem from Mui v5, if the input is valid. The border gets set inside `::before` and `::after` pseudoclasses.
I'm using `variant="standard"` for the TextFields.

I can apply the pseudoclasses to the MuiInput with stylesOverride and change the input styles. But that doesn't give me the desired result. E.g. if I have an input endAdornment the bottom-border stops in front of the adornment, because I only modify the `<input` styles and endAdornment is not the part of the input.

Any help would be appreciated :D.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code to help give clearer context?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with one solution let me know if it works for you

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-question-hzkx3c?file=/src/Demo.js

```
"& input:valid + fieldset": {
    borderColor: "#E0E3E7",
    borderWidth: 1
  },
"& input:invalid + fieldset": {
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 1
  },
"& input:valid:focus + fieldset": {
    borderLeftWidth: 4,
    padding: "4px !important" // override inline-style
  }
```

References - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#customization
Almost all code i have used from here only you can check this for more customization

Comment: This sadly doesn't work for me, because I'm using `variant="standard"`.